# Force arm-none-eabi-as to use strict add/sub immediate encoding?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, disassembly, thumb

I am writing a tool to disassemble ARM Thumb instructions into ARM Thumb assembly which can be reassembled into the original binary with a stock assembler ([plug](https://github.com/ChaoticConundrum/reassemble)). The "stock assembler" part seems to be the tricky bit. One particular instruction is giving me trouble.

Example:

The encoded thumb instruction `0x1f12` disassembles to `subs r2, r2, #4` with both `arm-none-eabi-objdump -D` and Capstone. According to [this document](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece222/ARM/ARM7-TDMI-manual-pt3.pdf) that is strictly correct (see 5.2 Format 2), and the immediate value is packed inside the third operand field.

However, when I assemble the instruction `subs r2, r2, #4` with `arm-none-eabi-as`, using the `.syntax unified` directive (this allows some flags on instructions that don't really have meaning in Thumb, like the `s` on the end of `subs`), I get `0x3a04`. This is functionally equivalent to the above encoding (see 5.3 Format 3), but it is different.

For my purposes, this quite complicates things (say a `subs` was inside a `tbb` table, which was naievely parsed as instructions, and re-encoded differently, that would be a nightmare to debug).

Question:

Is there a way to force `arm-none-eabi-as` to use Format 2 whenever the immediate value is within range? As it is, if I change either of the `r2` operands to another register, the instruction is encoded in Format 2 as desired, the only way possible. When the source and destination registers are the same, it encodes it in Format 3, regardless of the size of the immediate value.

Alternatives are also welcome, but I think my other options are customizing (or writing) the assembler, or just not disassembling the offending instructions.

Notes:

Removing `.syntax unified` does not change the encoding, it just allows `subs` to be assembled instead of `sub`.

Comment: May have to look at the source code for gnu as to figure this one out.

Comment: For ones you know it is going to get wrong you can just insert the machine code directly with .word or .byte or whatever the halfword one is I cant remember.

Comment: According to [this condensed reference guide](http://www.coranac.com/files/gba/re-ejected-gasref.pdf) I don't see anything usable (if the `sub r,r,#` input is already not enough). It may be incomplete, or not in sync with your version, but doing the `.word` with comment looks reasonable to me in this situation.

Comment: It should only happen when both registers are the same. Format 3 only has a single register.  You are worried about data that decodes as an instruction being transformed?  You should not have analyzed data as code!  Trying to circumvent this by getting GAS to verbatim encode seem like a band aid.  Some instructions in Thumb2 can be forced to be a wide encoding.  ARM may obsolete some duplicate opcodes (like `subs rN, rN, #x`) as it has another sensible encoding.  Things like execute never, etc. have been used to gain op-code space after being deprecated.

Comment: @artlessnoise You are right, a better solution is to more rigorously analyze the input. I was hoping to match the output exactly to the input, but as it is, they are functionally the same, and only the adds/subs encodings differ.

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with expecting this.  I was just giving a rational as to why GAS and any assembler might choose a particular encoding.  The instruction might be deprecated and/or non-existent in newer (or future) ARM CPUs.  I would try to get the basic block analysis (use flow control instructions) first and then mark sections as code/data.  Give the option to generate binary identical (with a macro like `subs_type2 rn, #constant` where the macro can be a standard tool include).  This gives a way to debug/diagnose basic block flaws in the tool.